# Объединение двух дисков через LVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm

Всем привет,

Я арендовал облачный сервер под Ubuntu на 20Гб и дополнительное дисковое пространство на 10Гб (это тестовый сервер, на реальном цифры будут больше). На скриншоте можно посмотреть, как пространство распределено по умолчанию:

[image: текущая разбивка]

Мне бы хотелось **объединить два диска в один на 30ГБ**, чтобы любая директория в корневом каталоге могла использовать всё свободное пространство, без разбивок и прочего. Я думал использовать для этого LVM (объединить два тома в группу и на её основании создать логический том), но проблема в том, что /dev/sda1 не инициализирован как Physical Volume, а значит я не могу производить с ним манипуляции через LVM. Я пробовал команду `pvcreate /dev/sda1`, но получаю ошибку *"Can't open /dev/sda1 exclusively. Mounted filesystem?"* - как я понимаю, дело в том что диск используется системой.

Вопрос: можно ли объединить sda1 и sdb в группу томов (и затем создать один логический том) и как это сделать?

P.S. Если это нельзя сделать через LVM, я готов рассмотреть и другие варианты, поскольку меня интересует только конечный результат.

Comment: Предположу, что нужно загрузиться с диска (не знаю как у вас, но как минимум VPS/VDS хостинги обычно позволяют загрузить свой ISO-образ) и переустановить систему с LVM

Comment: Поддержку, проще переустановить с настройкой LVM. Но если нет времени, хостер не дает, еще что-то... Может проще сделать [симлинки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0#UNIX-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) для тяжелых директорий на доп диск и не заморачиваться?

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. Их надо отформатьровать как PV сначала. Это не получится сделать на работающей с этого диска системе. Нужно переустановить систему на LVM.

Без этого Вам можно сделать такой маневр: уменьшить файловую систему, уменьшить раздел /dev/sda1 до 1,55ГБ, создать новый раздел и создать на нем том LVM, перенести корень и исправить загрузчик.

Самое сложное в этом маневре это уменьшить живой раздел: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226872/how-to-shrink-root-filesystem-without-booting-a-livecd/227318#227318

Если есть доступ к консоле сервера, то проще c перезагрузкой в initrd.